# Subscription billing with Stripe bundle in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, stripe-payments

I've been trying to find a good symfony2 bundle to handle Stripe subscription billing, however I haven't succeeded. This bundle seems to be the easiest: https://github.com/PaymentSuite/StripeBundle, but I don't know how to implement the subscription setup and stuff. I've created a plan in Stripe, and installed the bundle but I don't know where to go from here.

The only error is when I insert this piece of code into my project:

```
{% block content %}
    <div class="payment-wrapper">
    {{ stripe_render() }}
    </div>
{% endblock content %}

{% block foot_script %}
  {{ parent() }}
  {{ stripe_scripts() }}
{% endblock foot_script %}
```

It gives me the error:"An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Undefined variable: amount")".

Anyway I guess this doesn't have anything to do with the subscription billing anyway.

Hope someone can help!

Comment: Are you sure the error is in the piece of code that you are showing? I don't see any reference to an `amount` variable there

Comment: If I remove that piece of twig code, there error disappears

Answer (score 0):

This happen when you are configuring the [PaymentBridge](http://docs.paymentsuite.org/en/latest/configuration.html#paymentbridge-service) service, the function `{{stripe_render()}}` is rendering the payment form which use PaymentBridge.

So the method `getAmount()` from `PaymentBridge`  is returning an uninitialized variable, you can set the amount as a property.